# jQuery validate custom rule in data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, customvalidator

I have an input text which already has some validate rules

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Write the code here" 
       name="myCode" id="myCode" data-rule-required="true" 
       data-msg-required="Required field" class="form-control" 
       aria-required="true">
```

and have created a custom rule to validate the syntax of the code

```
$("#myCode").rules("add", { checkCode: 
    function () { 
        return $('input[name=codeText]').val(); 
    } 
});
```

With this method I am defining that `myCode` should be validated by using also `checkCode` method which in turns receive in input the value of `codeText`.

This works really very well. However to maintain clean the code I would like to move the rule definition inside a `data-*` attribute but I can't understand how to write the code to dynamically pass the equivalent of return `$('input[name=codeText]').val()`. Please have a look at the question marks below.

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Write the code here" 
       name="myCode" id="myCode" 
       data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Required field" 
       data-rule-checkCode="????" data-msg-checkCode="Invalid code" 
       class="form-control" aria-required="true">
```

What I have to put in the attribute value???

**EDIT**

As per [Sparky answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33057995/431537) I've ended up on putting all the selector on the attribute. Like this:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Write the code here" 
   [...]
   data-rule-checkCode="input[name=codeText]" 
   [...]>
```

and using it like this in my method

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkCode", function(value, element, param) {
    return $(param).val();
}, '...');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> and have created a custom rule to validate the syntax of the code

```
$("#myCode").rules("add", { checkCode: 
    function () { 
        return $('input[name=codeText]').val(); 
    } 
});
```

The `.rules()` method is **not** how you *create* a custom rule.  It's only how you *declare* existing rules on a particular input.

The. `.addMethod()` method is how you *create* a custom rule.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCode", function(value, element) {
    return $('input[name=codeText]').val();
}, 'Please enter a valid email address.');
```

Then you can use `.rules('add')` to assign it to your field...

```
$('input[name="myCode"]').rules('add', {
    checkCode: true
});
```

**See**:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

---

Alternatively, you can make the method generic by passing the `name` as a parameter...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkCode", function(value, element, param) {
    return $('input[name=' + param + ']').val();
}, 'Please enter a valid email address.');
```

Then *assign* it to your field...

```
$('input[name="myCode"]').rules('add', {
    checkCode: "codeText"
});
```

---

As far as using the data attributes, it's unclear why you need to do this when you're dynamically using the `.rules()` method.

Maybe after you properly create the `checkCode` rule, you can simply declare it using `data-rule-checkCode="true"` or `data-rule-checkCode="codeText"`.